r rlang::parse_quo(): security concerns; alternative method?
Edit:
It seems I didn't use the correct search terms.
Thanks to user Iroha:
See this answer which you can adapt for your needs (just follow the steps of setting up the safe environment and use it in parse_quo())
Obviously it takes a bit of investigative work to figure out which functions to whitelist, ?S4groupGeneric is the documentation that I used to decide which arguments to getGroupMembers() I needed to use.
Original:
My use case:

Query data from a database into a dataframe.
Create a new column in the dataframe using a calculation configured by a user, retrieved from a database.

A minimal way to do something like this:
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(10,20,20))

myfun <- function(df, expr) {
  df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      result = !!rlang::parse_quo(expr, env = rlang::caller_env())
    )
}

# the results work, I get what I want:
print(df %>% myfun("a + b"))
print(df %>% myfun("10 * a > b"))

# but is there a way to not execute arbitrary commands?
# I can use print():
print(df %>% myfun("print('This is not very secure!')"))
# and also, I can restart the R session:
print(df %>% myfun(".rs.restartR()"))

The calculations I intend the user to configure are either algebraic or logical. Other than that, they can be anything.
I control the database that I intend to use to store the expressions, and it's not something accessed from over the internet (only exposed to an internal network) so I have some control over the expressions. However, if someone is really capable of exploiting this, I can assume that they will know how to hack into the database, or call the function even without using the database.
Questions:

Is there another, secure solution to store user defined calculations somewhere, and retrieve them when a script runs?
Or, is there a way to limit which expressions are allowed (so that only the algebraic math operators +, -, *, /, ^ and (, and the logical operators & and | can be executed)?

